# Telegram bot not receiving updates when other bots are in the group

Tags: typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following code in my telegram bot in typescript to get notified when a user leaves a group:

```
import TelegramBot, { Message } from 'node-telegram-bot-api'

export const bot = new TelegramBot(MY_TOKEN, {
  webHook: {
    port: 8443,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  }
});

bot.on('left_chat_member', async (msg) => {
  console.log("LEFT")
})
```

The event gets triggered perfectly when my bot is the only bot available in the group. When I add other group management bots such as Rose, and I set them up to delete service messages (user X has left the group), the event no longer triggers. As if the other bots when deleting the message were stopping my bot from receiving the update.

I initially thought it was a problem linked to the polling update mechanism, hence I set the bot up to work with websockets. This did not fix the issue.

What am I doing wrong?